# Perl getting beginning of month for every month for last year but GMT hour added on

Tags: perl, datetime

I'm storing a collection of dates which are the previous 12 months starting from the beginning of the month. So I have:

```
my @t = localtime time();
my $m = $t[4];
my $y = $t[5];

foreach my $date (keys %$dates_ref) {
    $m -= $comparison{$date}; # a hash of numbers to go back the correct number of months
    $dates_ref->{$date} = mktime(0,0,0,1,$m,$y);
}
```

I end up with a bunch of dates like so: 
Current month: `1356998400` which is:

`Tue Jan 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`

Last 12 months:

```
1325376000 - Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
1328054400 - Wed Feb 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
1330560000 - Thu Mar 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
1333238400 - Sun Apr 01 2012 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
1335830400 - Tue May 01 2012 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
1338508800 - Fri Jun 01 2012 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
1341100800 - Sun Jul 01 2012 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
1343779200 - Wed Aug 01 2012 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
1346457600 - Sat Sep 01 2012 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
1349049600 - Mon Oct 01 2012 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
1351728000 - Thu Nov 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
1354320000 - Sat Dec 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

As you can see, April to October have the GMT hour added on. What is the best way of getting it to *not* do this, so it just starts at `00:00`?

E.g. `1333238400` would become `1333234800`

Comment: The GMT has nothing to to with the extra hour. It comes from daylight saving time. What exactly do you want to do with these values? Do you need the epoch value or the string?

Comment: @simbabque the epoch value, I put the string as evidence of what is my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) module, and properly handle the time zones. This is an example:

```
  my $dt = DateTime->new(
      year      => 2000,
      month     => 5,
      day       => 10,
      hour      => 15,
      minute    => 15,
      time_zone => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  );

  print $dt->hour; # prints 15

  $dt->set_time_zone( 'America/Chicago' );

  print $dt->hour; # prints 17
```

Comment: It's not really a time zone problem per se... all I'm dealing with is GMT, but it gets the daylight savings time added on in summer. DateTime has `is_dst()` to check if it is in effect, but I'm not sure of how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to install CPAN modules, I'd suggest using Date::Calc - it will let you convert to GMT instead of to your local timezone,

Comment: I've been studying `Date::Calc`, but I'm not sure what I could use to convert to GMT... `timezone` finds out if there is a difference which doesn't help convert it and I've tested the inbuilt `mktime` with the same results. Is there a particular method you would suggest using?

Comment: And if it makes any difference, being in the UK I'm on GMT at the moment, it's just the DST difference in summer which is creating the problem.

Comment: There's the function `Gmtime ($year,$month,$day, $hour,$min,$sec, $doy,$dow,$dst) = Gmtime([time]);` which tells you if DST is added, so you can remove it if you like. But probably DateTime is better, as Miguel Prz suggested.

Comment: Not that I think this is the solution to the problem, but why recommend Date::Calc over the (effectively) standard DateTime?

Comment: Too much blood in the caffeine stream at the time of writing the answer. Also, see the last sentence of the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

use gmtime instead of localtime in the first line of your script

Comment: That was my first thought too, but I don't see how it changes things - the GMT thing happens when the script works with dates calculated later, not with the localtime.